# How to redirect to React Native Expo app from Webview after Stripe payment?

Tags: react-native, webview, stripe-payments, expo, deep-linking

I'm currently developing a mobile application using React Native Expo. In order to avoid detaching I'm using the Stripe client-only checkout page in a WebView.

My question is how do I redirect a successful/cancelled payment back to a specific screen in my application from the WebView?

Comment: The Green Tick of Approval is the standard way of indicating a question has been resolved for the asker; no need to add "[SOLVED]" or anything like that. You could have known because no other questions have that (unless they do; then it'll be removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is use [Deep Links](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html) as the return URL which should allow you to get right back into the app - and you can use the path to specify exactly where it should land.

Comment: Do I need to detach from expo to use deep linking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there, but Deep Linking provides a way to get back into a specific spot in your app (assuming you have a handler for it), so you would have to be outside of your app to make use of it...?

Comment: Unfortunately deep links don't appear to work with stripe. It doesn't register as a working successUrl. Instead I want to try hijacking the returned url and navigate back to a screen from my WebView before it's loaded. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Oh, ya, ok - it might not work with Checkout, fair enough.  What you'll likely want to do here is have a server side URL that you can redirect to, that will then redirect back to the deep link.

Comment: Yep! That's what I ended up doing. Got an EC2 instance listening for requests that redirect based on paths /successful and /cancelled. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue - if you know what the redirect url will look like ahead of time... This is what I did... so in my case lets call my url `http://google.com`

```
   render() {
      return (
      
       <WebView
         onNavigationStateChange={ 
             (e) => { 
               if(e.url == "https://www.google.com/") this.props.navigation.navigate("NewsFeed")
             }
          }
       source={{ uri: 'https://a-url-to-load' }} style={styles.WebView} />
      )
   };
  }
```

Of course you should extract that function out to do more complex stuff... etc

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler than deep linking back to the application, as suggested in the accepted answer.